# Taking part of string in python error

Tags: python, string, pandas, parsing

I got an error `Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`
For this code

```
newestdata = newestdf.assign(
        idobject=newestdf.index.str.split('/').str[1].str.replace("-", "").str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int))
```

What I used to take a part of this:

```
OOOO-ASAS/INTEL-64646/OOOO-15445/PPPO-9
```

But that's what happens in one python script, but in another don't, it works well. Do you have an idea what is the problem?

Comment: Obviously `newestdf.index` - whatever it might be (I assume a panda dataframe ?) - is not what you expect it to be. But since we don't have the slightest clue on what it actually is nor what it contains etc there's no way we can help...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers
Yes, it's pandas dataframe.
This is the value (one of the values) of the first column. 
OOOO-ASAS/INTEL-64646/OOOO-15445/PPPO-9

Comment: Please post a minimal _complete_ and _verifiable_ example (the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue), cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem you have mixed data - some numeric with `strings` in `index`.

Need cast to `string` as first step:

```
newestdata = newestdf.assign(
        idobject=newestdf.index.astype(str).str.split('/').str[1].str.replace("-", "").str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int))
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```